# Android XML parsing, Documentbuilder throws exception

Tags: android, xml, parsing, exception

So, I'm trying to parse an XML file in my Android app using nodelist and documentbuilder. Problem is, Documentbuilder.parse() always returns null and ends up throwing an IOException. I'm guess it has something to do with the filepath being wrong.

```
public class EquiScoreActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ProtocolFactory.GetProtocolFactory().LoadProtocol("EquiScore/assets/Protocols/LC1_2008.xml");
    }
}

public class ProtocolFactory 
{
    private static ProtocolFactory m_Instance = new ProtocolFactory();
    Document dom;

    private ProtocolFactory()
    {
    }

    public static ProtocolFactory GetProtocolFactory()
    {
        return m_Instance;
    }

    public Protocol LoadProtocol(String filename)
    {
        Protocol output = null;
        List<JudgementGroup> jGroups;
        List<GeneralAssesment> gAssesment;

        ParseXmlFile(filename);
        ParseDocument();

        return output;
    }


    private void ParseXmlFile(String filename)
    {
        //get the factory
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        try 
        {
            //Using factory get an instance of document builder
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            //parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file
            dom = db.parse(filename);
        }
        catch(ParserConfigurationException pce)
        {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(SAXException se) 
        {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) 
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Basically I need to know how to get the proper filepath or some other (maybe better?) way to parse the XML. Each node of one type can have differing numbers of child nodes, which is why I figured this approach would be a good one.

The IOException is: 
"MalformedURLException"
"Protocol not found: EquiScore/assets/Protocols/LC1_2008.xml"

I've tried various variations of the filename but seem to get this error anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The `IOException` you're receiving is due to the fact that what you're passing is a bare pathname while [`DocumentBuilder.parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) expects a URL.

The first part of the URL is called "protocol" (it's the `http` in `http://www.google.com`). Your pathname doesn't specify a protocol and hence the error reads "Protocol not found". You can make a URL out of a pathname by prepending `file://` to it.

Alternatively, you can create a [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) or [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) object and pass it to `DocumentBuilder.parse()` since the method is overloaded. For example like this:

```
dom = db.parse(new File(filename));
```

EDIT: Since your file is in the `assets/` folder you can use [`AssetManager.open()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29) which returns `InputStream` which is in turn accepted by one of the overloaded versions of `DocumentBuilder.parse()`:

```
AssetManager assetManager = ...
dom = db.parse(assetManager.open("Protocols/LC1_2008.xml"));
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me down to a "File not found" error at least! :)
Now I just need to figure out the path to my file..
It's located in assets/Protocols/, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well, assets (stuff in the assets/ folder) are accessed through the AssetManager API - not File or URLs.

Comment: Alright, so what would be the best course of action? Create a new folder, something like res/XML/Protocols and get it from there?

Edit: Well, I'm trying this but can't get it to find the files anyway. I must be thinking the wrong way about the filepath or the whole thing?

Comment: well, i added an answer for "the way to go".

Comment: @Bentebent Try [AssetManager.list()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#list(java.lang.String)) to list the paths of all the assets bundled with your app. Maybe there is something wrong with the path you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you've placed the XML in the assets folder, thus you should use the `AssetManager` to retrieve an `InputStream` to parse.

Something like this:

```
Context context = ...;
AssetManager assManager = context.getAssets();
DocumentBuilder db = ..;
db.parse(assManager.open("Protocols/LC1_2008.xml"));
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the help, this seems to have solved the problem!